# How vscode implement JSDoc comment suggestions?

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions

In VSCode, when you type `/**` above a function line, you will get the JSDoc comment suggestion.

[image: the gif for showing steps]

I want to know the source code of this feature and the Implementation principle so that I can implement a similar feature in my extension.

I only know this feature is provided by the built-in extension 'TypeScript and JavaScript Language Features' (Because it disappeared when I disabled the extension).

[image: build-in extension 'TypeScript and JavaScript Language Features']

And I know that the source code for the extension is in [vscode - github](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/tree/main/extensions/typescript-language-features).

Comment: look for a `CompletionItemProvider`

Comment: Why doesn't this work any longer? I never disabled it.

Comment: I have no intention of disabling it. This is just how I find out which extension provides JsDoc suggestion function.